# How Create Background Service for each order In Android Programming?

Tags: android, timer, scheduler, background-service

*We are developing an Android 6 tablet app.*

The app aims to take orders from real time database.

my problem is:

> When a new order received a timer must run as a android service.(For
>   each order a new timer which lives 3 minutes must run)
>
> After timer is run out a function must be call( for each order a
>   separate timer have to run. How could we do?

**Do you have any idea to solve problem.**

Thanks

Comment: Try android.os.Handler().postDelayed(runnable,timer)

Comment: When the app close or send to background, services still must run. We aim to warn user even app run in background.thanks

Comment: Ok then look for intentservice perform your long running task and upon completion send a broadcast.  You can register to listen for broadcast.  It can help you achieve what you need

Comment: IntentService is for short lived tasks handled in a queue. Read this: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Managing-Threads-and-Custom-Services. You can run a foreground service (with a low priority notification) which spawns a worker `HandlerThread`. Then post delayed runnables to associated `Handler`.